# Fractal box dimension: 2D vs 3D?

Tags: geometry

Is there any difference when using box counting method in 2D dimension and 3D dimension when I applied it to an image?

1) 2D case: the image is converted to a binary image, then we try using boxes to cover the shape

2) 3D case: use 3D boxes to cover the image?

http://www.wahl.org/fe/HTML_version/link/FE4W/FE4W_files/image563.gif

I'm thinking that 3D case will be higher, is it true?

Comment: This was [crossposted to MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126313/fractal-box-dimension-2d-vs-3d). In the future, please wait some time before posting your question in multiple fora, and when you do, provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to see hear from you that you'd already gotten the solution elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Well, 3D box counting can be used on a 2D image that uses gray scale to make it a "3D" image which can be useful. I don't know what application you are using the FD for.